# Не дает работать с итератором j

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Коллеги, добрый день, не даёт работать с итератором в вложённом цикле. i пропускает, а j подчеркивает красной линией, что я делаю неправильно???. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void FillArray(int arr[], const int rows, const int cols)
{
srand(time(NULL));
bool AlreadyThere;
int RandomNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        AlreadyThere = false;
        RandomNumber = rand() % 20;
        for (int jj = 0; jj < j; jj++)
        {
            if (RandomNumber == arr[i][j])
            {
                AlreadyThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!AlreadyThere)
        {
            arr[i][j] = RandomNumber;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Что такое у вас `arr`? **Одно**мерный массив. Так как вы можете обращаться `arr[i][j]`?

Comment: Спасибо))) Но теперь я добавил еще одни [], теперь они выделяются красным

Comment: При передаче двумерного массива в функцию следует указать вторую размерность, причем она должна быть известна во время компиляции. Ну, или использовать в функции обращение как к элементу одномерного массива, пользуясь тем, что элементы в нем располагаются в одном блоке построчно.